# Do we need to ban the `beginners` tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta-tags

I've seen a number of questions tagged [beginners](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginners) recently.

This is a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) which doesn't add anything to the question or site.

What benefit, if any, does anyone think that this tag brings?

If there is no benefit I propose to remove the tag from all existing posts and re-tag any posts left [untagged](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) in the process.

**UPDATE**

The tag has been manually removed from all posts, [learning](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) seemed an appropriate replacement in a number of circumstances.

Comment: [learning](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/learning) might be a suitable replacement for several of them.  I support banning the beginners tag.

Comment: [junior-programmer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/junior-programmer) might be a good one for some of them as well, as in the case of [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/294/how-can-i-find-a-good-open-source-project-to-join) where "beginners" was not a meta-tag at all.

Comment: The learning tag also adds no value as all posts should be tagged as 'learning'!

Comment: @Gary - it's slightly better than "beginner" but you're free to suggest a tag edit if you feel it's warranted. A few more up-votes and you'll be able to do it yourself.

Comment: It's not slightly better, it's worse if anything. I don't mean to be rude, it's just that all questions on all stack exchange sites could potentially be marked as 'learning'. You understand what i mean? The questions should be tagged strictly as per their content, not by perceived benefit for users. P.S. i don't care about my rep here, only the stackoverflow one matters. ;op

Comment: @Gary - I do understand what you mean.

Comment: @Gary If you browse through the questions, you'll see what is meant by "learning".  You can learn from all questions, but those questions are *about* learning. Like Chris said, you're free to suggest a different name, but the grouping is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this even mean anything when used *correctly*? [Mark notes](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/do-we-need-to-ban-the-beginners-tag/1475#1475) that since programmers themselves are on-topic for the site it could be used to refer to questions *about* beginners...

...But who is a beginner? The kid typing his [first "Hello world" program](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60406/which-programming-language-first-introduced-hello-world)? The freshman [about to attend class](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51669/getting-started-and-learning-programming)? The new graduate starting his [first real-world project](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70661/how-big-is-the-gap-between-what-you-learn-in-cs-curriculums-and-what-you-need-in)? The [polyglot programmer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46045/why-is-it-always-what-language-should-i-learn-next-instead-of-what-project-sho) trying to make sense of Ruby? Beginner as a description for a person means very different things in different contexts, much more so than a *role* like [team-leader](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-leader).

A similar tag is [great-programmer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/great-programmer), where a disturbing number of the questions tagged are concerned with *[de](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9055/what-are-the-big-contemporary-names-in-the-programming-field)[fi](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7749/how-do-you-go-from-a-so-so-programmer-to-a-great-one)[ni](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/is-it-possible-to-become-a-good-programmer-if-you-dont-like-math)[ng](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/when-can-you-call-yourself-good-at-language-x) [wh](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4711/what-are-the-most-common-schools-of-knowledge-prevalent-in-great-programmers)[at](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3849/when-would-someone-be-considered-a-great-programmer) [it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28/what-personal-qualities-make-for-a-successful-programmer) [me](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7439/which-web-site-gives-the-most-accurate-indication-of-a-programmers-capabilities)[an](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14052/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-super-programmer)[s](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50818/is-it-possible-to-measure-if-someone-is-a-good-programmer)*...

[Mark argues](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/do-we-need-to-ban-the-beginners-tag/1475#1475) that beginner could be useful for a person starting their professional life to find questions about other people in the same situation. But Renesis suggests the [junior-programmer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/junior-programmer) tag for this, which is probably a better choice seeing as I can only find a couple of questions tagged "beginners" that actually fit this criteria.

Regardless of how it *could* be used, [beginners](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginners) **is** primarily used as a meta-tag. They're not questions *about* beginners, they're questions *from* beginners! For the vast majority of the questions currently tagged `beginners`, [learning](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), [teaching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) and [education](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) are all better choices.

Let's get rid of it.

Comment: OK - what's the best way to proceed? There are currently 36 questions tagged with `beginner` which is probably just about manageable for a manual retag effort. Or should we just delete the tag from the database (can mods do this?) and then retag specific questions later?

Comment: @ChrisF: let's just manually retag them, shouldn't take long. In most cases, the tag can simply be removed, but there are a handful with *only* [beginners] (or [beginners] and one other tag).

Comment: Right I'll make a start.

Comment: You guys are making the 'feature' of no distinction between an edit, an answer, and a new question on the front page to be *very* (annoyingly) obvious right now...

Comment: @Jonathan: it's like ripping off a bandage... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Programmers.SE has a somewhat unique mission in that we're about *being programmers* instead of *doing programming*.

So, the one use I can see for it is for questions that are about *starting out* as a professional programmer. If I'm a tenderfoot programmer, it stands to reason I'd be interested in questions about starting out as a programmer in and of themselves, which would make [beginners](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginners) not necessarily a meta-tag.

Some of the questions are used in that sense, but some aren't: a tag wiki might help clarify the intended use. Otherwise, it might be worth exploring another tag under which to categorize those questions.

---

#### Potential Tag Wiki Excerpt

> These questions are about being an entry-level or beginner programmer.

#### Potential Tag Wiki Body

> *Todo, should include examples of tag misuse*

Comment: Good point. If we can come up with a good tag wiki for it then...

Comment: After looking through the highest-voted beginners questions, I agree with this, though in this use, is it a synonym of **junior-programmer**?

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to think of a reason I would want to see all questions tagged as 'beginners' and I can't think of one.

Perhaps it's the several decades that have passed since I was one but I can't for the life of me see why that would be useful.

Comment: It's been...less time for me, and I agree.

Answer (score 0):

These tags were actively being deleted as they add no value. I would of though this one wants deleting too.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

[Can't keep a good tag down!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60318/cant-keep-a-good-tag-down)