# Do we need to black list the [beginners] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-blacklist

A while ago we cleaned up the [beginners](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginners) tag, but it has returned.

[Do we need to ban the `beginners` tag?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/do-we-need-to-ban-the-beginners-tag)

Is now the time to request it gets added to the black list (after another clean up)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(waves hands)

You must be imagining it... I see no [beginner](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) or [beginners](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginners) tag... indeed you can't even enter those - they're rejected at the point of entry!

> ...these aren't the tags you're looking for...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, since it's [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). In fact, [beginner](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) is explicitly mentioned in the blog post. Although I would suspect that the clean up wouldn't be that much cleaning up. I looked at the questions and most and otherwise appropriately tagged. Perhaps it could just be obliterated rather than a full clean-up.

Comment: I don't think it would be a very good practice to simply obliterate it. We would get a lot of untagged questions that we would have to retag anyway...

Comment: @Dynamic actually none of those questions have untagged as their only tag, plus it's a lot easier to go through a small amount of untagged questions as opposed to going through a much larger amount of Qs and retagging them